# Fn+F2 does not switch WIFI on/off on Asus 1015e

Tags: wireless, function-keys

Wifi works ok but can not be switched on/off with fn+f2.
I have an Asus 1015e-DS03 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS fresh install (no dual-boot).

Linux ASUS-1015E-DS03 3.8.0-35-generic #52~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:24:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Problem may be located in asus_nb_wmi driver.

Please, if you have the same problem, add yourself to the Bug Report # 1277959.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-raring/+bug/1277959

Thank you.

```
christian@ASUS-1015E-DS03:~$ lsmod | grep asus
asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24794  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13890  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    19256  1 asus_wmi
video                  19574  2 i915,asus_wmi

christian@ASUS-1015E-DS03:~$ rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

christian@ASUS-1015E-DS03:~$ lsmod | grep -e ath9k -e asus
ath9k                 161996  0 
mac80211              619465  1 ath9k
ath9k_common           13859  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              457667  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
ath                    24123  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24794  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13890  1 asus_wmi
cfg80211              499466  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
wmi                    19256  1 asus_wmi
video                  19574  2 i915,asus_wmi
```

Comment: Did you try options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1?

Comment: The other available options are 0 and 4. Are they also ineffective? Did you try sudo modprobe -rf asus-wmi?

Comment: Yes, I tried with values wapf=0...9, Nothing. Only value=0 disables wifi. Yes, I tried  sudo modprobe -rf asus-wmi, sudo modprobe -rf asus-nb-wmi and sudo modprobe asus-nb-wmi. Nothing. I also read your replies on thread #2173539. Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It appears that you've tried and not been successful with everything I'm aware of. Sorry.

Comment: Fn+F8 (screens switching) stop working. Do you think there may be any conflict?

Comment: Hard to say. Is there any change when you manipulate Fn+F8 and then run: rfkill list all?

Comment: Hard/Soft blocked: all no. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes. So you are looking for a way to switch wireless _off_, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. I want to fix the Fn+F2 combo and the Fn+F8 (used to work). Where should I copy the result of lsmod | grep asus so that you take a look?

Comment: I'm sure I already know: asus-wmi, asus-nb-wmi, wmi,video and sparse-keymap. Can you turn off wireless with sudo rfkill block all?

Comment: Yes, they are soft killed (wifi & ethernet).

Comment: I made a clean install and now asus_nb_wmi is not present anymore in etc/modeprobe.d. How is this?

Comment: Because /etc/modprobe.d is where you, the user, add driver parameters. If you haven't added it yet, that's why it isn't there. Is it loaded as expected? From the terminal: lsmod | grep asus

Comment: I've just added the info.

Comment: If you have tried every option in asus-nb-wmi and have also tried simply removing asus-wmi, then that last option I know of is to map some other key, F9 for example, to send the signal: rfkill block all and F10: rfkill unblock all. BTW, rfkill does not affect ethernet at all. If you'd like to try, I will write an answer.

Comment: Yes please, but use F3 instead. Thanks.

Comment: In the answer I will post, you can select any key you want.

Comment: This bug has been reported on Launchpad long ago. Still there is no fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Until this issue is fixed with newer updates, you may use "xbindkeys" tool to set a hotkey (can be a single key or a key-combination) of your choice to toggle the WiFi enabled/disabled. This is how.

1) First, we create a script (for ease of use, and so that we can toggle it on/off using the same hotkey) -

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # Script to toggle the wireless blocked/unblocked

    # index no. of phy interface
    IFACE=`rfkill list all | grep phy | cut -c 1`

    # WiFi block state 0=active, 1=blocked
    BLOCKED=`rfkill list all | grep -iA1 phy | grep -ic soft.*yes`

    if [ $BLOCKED -eq 1 ]; then
        rfkill unblock $IFACE

    else
        rfkill block $IFACE
    fi
```

Copy-paste the contents of the above box in a text file and save this file in your Home directory with the name wifitoggle.sh. Make sure the file starts with (without double quotes) "#!/bin/bash" and ends with the "fi" being its last line.

2) Make the script executable:

```
    chmod +x wifitoggle.sh
```

3) Create a symlink to this script in /bin directory:

```
    sudo ln -s $HOME/wifitoggle.sh /bin
```

B. Bind the Script with a HotKey of your choice :

1) Install xbindkeys-config (a GUI frontend to xbindkeys - the program that captures and binds hotkeys with commands)

```
    sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config
```

2) Create a default config file for it (else it would crash on key capture step)

```
    xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

3) Run the program from the terminal (because it does not create a launcher in Unity dash)

```
    xbindkeys-config
```

Leave the terminal running in the background. In the GUI box that opens, 3 example shortcuts are already present. You may leave them.

4) Click on "New" button at the bottom of the GUI.

5) In the right hand pane of the GUI, fill in a suitable name in the "Name" field, e.g. "Toggle Wifi"

6) Click on "Get Key" button. This will open a tiny blank box doing nothing but waiting for your input.

7) Press the desired key (or key combination) that you want for toggling Wifi on/off. For example, "F3" key (as it remains mostly unused). The tiny box will disappear and the key will be recorded.

8) In the "Action" field, type this -

```
    /bin/bash /bin/wifitoggle.sh
```

9) Click on "Apply" button and test the hotkey to see if it works as expected.

10) Click on "Save & Apply & Exit" to save the new hotkey to the default file and exit.

From now on, as soon as you will press this key or the key-combination, the wifi will change its state from On to Off, or Off to On.

The Fn key doesn't seem to be noticed by any key capture program I could find (probably that's why it is considered "Hardware Switch"), so it's not possible to use it yet.

I'd request that you submit a bug report against the problem, and point to this thread as a possible workaround. I have not found an applicable bug, so you will probably need to file a new one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/